# ASP:Binding to button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am having a repeater within it there is label bounded with the Parking_Name Field and a button which is bouned to the Parking_ID field.

`<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemDataBound="repeater1_ItemDataBound"> <ItemTemplate> <li> <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" "><%#Eval("Parking_Name")%> </asp:Label></div> <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CommandArgument = '<%#Eval("Parking_ID")%>'` />

How can bound the button with the Parking_Name as well ?

Regards

Comment: do you want to Parking_Name  to button text property ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Parking_Name")%>' CommandArgument = '<%#Eval("Parking_ID")%>' />
```

**Edit**

use like this

```
 <a href='page.aspx?Parking_Name=<%#Eval("Parking_Name")%>&ParkingCost=<%#Eval("ParkingCost")%>'><%#Eval("Parking_Name")%></a>
```

get both on page.aspx.cs like this

```
string Parking_Name =Request.QueryString["Parking_Name"];
string ParkingCost =Request.QueryString["ParkingCost"];
```

Comment: @Govind KamalaPrakash Malviya thanks. what I meant is that the button should hold the `parking_ID` value and `Parking_Name` + `ParkingCost` value so that I can pass them to another form.

Comment: @Govind KamalaPrakash Malviya any solution would be worth it to try !!

Comment: @Govind KamalaPrakash Malviya thanks. No value is being passed

Comment: did u see a tags in rendered html?

Comment: @Govind KamalaPrakash Malviya I need to assign the values required to the button so i can pass them as a session to the other form